# Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Getting below error while creating above deployment file. Kindly help

> error when creating "E_deployment.yml": Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.serviceName"

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeploy
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    type: db
    env: dev
spec:
  serviceName: newservice
  replicas: 2
  selector:

    matchLabels:
      app: amazon
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: amazon
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: volumeforpvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: volumepvc
      containers:
        - name: cont-1
          image: mysql
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
            requests:
              cpu: 200m
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volumeforpvc
              mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
          env:
            - name: MYSQL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DATABASE_URL
                  name: myconfigmap
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: The error is saying that you can’t have `serviceName` in the `spec` section. It’s not part of the specification so it should not be there. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/deployment-v1/#DeploymentSpec

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self descriptive here - **strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.serviceName"**
Deployment's spec does not support any field called **serviceName**. In order for your deployment to exposed via a service, declare a service separately with the selector matching the pod labels in your deployment manifest.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: newservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: amazon
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort:3306
```

And remember to remove the **serviceName** field from your deployment spec.

For more details about kubernetes deployment manifests and service manifests, please reach out to the official kubernetes website.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/